# SELECT and UPDATE queries with same where clause getting different row count results?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6

Using MySQL 5.6.

I was using an update query

```
UPDATE listtimeentry 
SET quoteId = 5683, 
lastAlteredQte="2020-04-10 11:06:14", 
userIdQte=1112, 
roleIdQte=10 
WHERE soId = 2488 AND quoteId IS NULL;
```

Which was telling me that 0 rows were affected, 0 rows were matched so nothing was updated.  This confused me as I knew what the data was and knew there should be somethings that were affected.  So I did a `SELECT` with with the same criteria -

```
SELECT * FROM listtimeentry
WHERE soId = 2488 AND quoteId IS NULL;
```

and this was returning 4 rows to me.  How is my `UPDATE` is not affecting anything while a `SELECT` with the same criteria shows there should be things getting affected?  An additional fact about this db is that `SQL_SAFE_UPDATES` is off.

How can this be and how can I change my `UPDATE` statement to affect the 4 rows that my `SELECT` statement is grabbing?

Edit:  If I run the select query I get this

```
id    soId    quoteId    userIdQte    roleIdQte    lastAlteredQte
=======================================================
101   2488    NULL       NULL         NULL         NULL
106   2488    NULL       NULL         NULL         NULL
192   2488    NULL       NULL         NULL         NULL
206   2488    NULL       NULL         NULL         NULL
```

And the relevant parts of the `SHOW CREATE` statment

```
CREATE TABLE `listtimeentry` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `soId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `roleIdQte` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `userIdQte` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastAlteredQte` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastAlteredAfterConfirmationQte` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `notNeeded` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `qteNeeded` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `quoteId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `userIdQte` (`userIdQte`),
  CONSTRAINT `listtimeentry_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`userIdQte`) REFERENCES `listusers` (`idx`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=118783 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

There is one trigger for the the table `listtimeentry` that runs after `INSERT`

```
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO `tab`.`listlineitems` SET 
    `listlineitems`.`itemId` = NEW.`id`,
    `listlineitems`.`type` = 1;
END
```

Edit:  Closing this.  There was something wrong with my server.  Somehow I was getting cached results with my SELECT statement but when UPDATE tried to run it failed.  I restarted my MySQL 5.6 Server and everything works fine know.  I don't know what caused this unfortunately though.

Comment: Can you show the 4 rows you think should have updated.

Comment: OK I added it.  These are all brand new columns with `DEFAULT NULL`.

Comment: where is the `soId` column in your sample table?

Comment: Just added it as well as the relevant parts of the `CREATE` statement.

Comment: Is there the value `1112` in the column idx of the table listusers?

Comment: That was a transposition error.  My company uses the convention to use `idx` instead of `id` in our db tables, however I think most people are familiar with using `id` so I changed it to that in my post. I forget to change it there.

Comment: @forpas Yes there is.

Comment: What you are claiming seems to be impossible - are you sure no errors are shown and are there any triggers on this table (if so please add the relevant code)

Comment: There is one trigger after insert.  Just added it.

Answer (score 0):

When you run `UPDATE` statement - MySQL will not update columns where the new value is the same as the old value. This creates the possibility the number of affected rows may not actually equal the number of rows matched, only the number of rows that were literally affected by the query.

If you want you can use a `REPLACE` statement, which first deletes the record with the same primary key and then inserts the new row.

Comment: But quoteid should have changed and if the update had been successful the select should not have found anything.

Comment: These are all brand new columns with `DEFAULT NULL` definitions, I am not setting any of them to null in my `UPDATE` statement so I don't think there's any columns where the old value is the same as the new value.